# Browsersync camera acces video.play is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, browser-sync, webcam-capture

Hi guys I started today to use browsersync with the simple configuration from https://browsersync.io/#install in a project to use the webcam to capture a picture. It was working pretty well but suddenly it stop working, now it doesn't show me the image from the camera and in chrome now appears the error **video.play is not a function** even with a gulp file to start the local server, so don't know what happened. Does anyone have had a problem like this before?

This is my js file:

```
(function(){
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.msGetUserMedia;

navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
}, function(stream) {
    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
}, function(error){
    //An error occured
    //error.code
});

document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function(){
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
    photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
});
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with complete same sourcecode. I migrated my camera image solution to yii2, and my problem was that the #video is a div element and not video element, if you change it to video tag it will work perfectly.

:)